# Mac - XCode - Record streaming video

Tags: macos, video-streaming

I am writing a Mac application that plays the streaming video.
I'll use Media player framework to play the video. Is there any way to record the video, save it and view it at a later time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the AVFoundation framework.  Specifically, the AVCaptureSession class and related classes.  [Here's the manual.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW14)